# Is there a way to print the configured route handlers on a tornado web server internally?

Tags: python, tornado

given the following (sample) handlers (taken from [here](https://raw.github.com/facebook/tornado/master/demos/facebook/facebook.py)):

```
handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/auth/login", AuthLoginHandler),
            (r"/auth/logout", AuthLogoutHandler),
        ]
```

is there a way to programmatically print the handlers on a separate page? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/auth/login", AuthLoginHandler),
            (r"/auth/logout", AuthLogoutHandler),
            (r"/routes", RoutePrinter),
        ]

...

class RoutePrinter(...):
    def get(self):
       self.write(str(self.application.routes))
```

which gives me 
`[(<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x216c130>, [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ])]`

I've tried a few different accessors but doesn't really help. Is it possible to generate a list of my routes?

**EDIT**

Based on further searching, I have come across ways to print a pattern/flag from these regex objects. The problem is that I am having a hard time understanding how to unnest them since it is not as intuitive as `self.application.handlers[0][0]` and then `self.application.handlers[1][0]`. The second is "out of range" even though it looks like it should be "/auth/login".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
[handler.regex.pattern for handler in self.application.handlers[0][1]]
```

If you also want the names of the handler classes:

```
[(handler.regex.pattern, handler.handler_class) for handler in self.application.handlers[0][1]]
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Tornado 4.5+ ever since the routing configuraiton enhancement.